# C define statement function called once or every time macro is used?

Tags: c, macros

In the following C code, will this macro replace all instances of `MIN_WORDS` with `size_to_words(0)` or will it be replaced with the result of that function call?

```
#define MIN_WORDS size_to_words(0)
```

I don't want the performance overhead of calling the function every time.

Comment: Function calls happens at run-time. Macro replacement happen at compile-time.

Comment: Also, unless your function is lengthy and takes a lot of time, the actual *calling* of a function is quick enough to be near unmeasurable. You're not attempting to do any [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)?

Comment: "don't want" or "can't have"? I rarely optimize unless there are several factors or even magnitudes of speed to gain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question, to understand whats happening you need to recognize these two things.

- macros are resolved by the preprocessor
- function calls are resolved during program execution

What will happen is the following:

- When you compile your code that includes macros, the preprocessor
  will first replace all macros with their definitions.
- when your executable is created it will be created with all those
  function calls. During run time, you will be calling that function
  each time.

If you compile with optimization flags it might optimize unnecessary function calls out for you though, check out gcc -O3 and -O2 flags and see what they do.

tl;dr: The preprocessor won't resolve function calls and optimize your code, so if your macro is a function your code will call the function unless optimizations are done for you.